# Layout for fuses with fuse holder

Tags: design, layout, board, bom

I am designing a PCB with a throughhole mounted fuse holder (ALTIUM designer).
Is there a standard way of sketching a fuse (for ex: [5HF 12-R](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/bel-fuse-inc/5HF-12-R/2257995)
, laying them out with the fuse holder footprint (for ex: [FC-211-22](https://www.digikey.co.il/en/products/detail/bel-fuse-inc/FC-211-22/622587)
) and having all of them (fuse and two holders, one from each side of the fuse) in the generated BOM?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the type property of the fuse as "mechanical". It won't be included in the ECO to the PCB but will be in the generated BOM.

https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/schematic-placement-editing-techniques#!part_properties